# multipart/form-data post api not working on hcloud

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, cloud, web-hosting

when we have deploying web api in hcloud https environment, only multipart/form-data request method not working in mobile app (Android or ios) but postman working fine.

try to find solutions but not get, please help

Comment: Try posting some code.

Comment: sir, this is not coding issue, i am facing that issue on hcloud environment, this works fine in our hosting environment. thanks. now i have found the solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that action(Post method) i am sending data in string  format , on server side(hcloud) url scanner refused the action because some special character.

Now passing the data in josn format, it works fine